# How to print pointer content in GDB?

Tags: gdb

In GDB I am trying:

> gdb> p/s *0x0804b680

Which gives me:

> $6 = 0x6c627550

Clearly it should have printed out `lbruP`, or am I wrong?

Comment: Which I did. So I'm sure my GDB is malfunctioning since it is outputting only half of the answer. Usually the output will be "$6 = 0x6c627550  'lbruP'".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

for
char* p = "abcde";

do

```
p /s p
```

e.g. not *p

```
(gdb) p /s p
$9 = 0x40060c "abcde"
```

If your p is not of type char* (e.g, void* v = p ) you can cast it or use the x command

```
(gdb) p /s (char*)v
$7 = 0x40061c "abcde"
(gdb) x /s v
0x40061c:    "abcde"
```

Comment: That's because p is already a pointer type. In my case 0x0804b680 is just a number and when 'p /s 0x0804b680' outputs '0x0804b680'. By prefixing '*', I'm telling GDB to treat 0x0804b680 as a pointer instead.